# Facebook-WordPress comment/feedback integration

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Currently I have my Facebook profile automatically republish blog posts from a WordPress instance.

What I would like to be able to do, however, is to also have comments posted to either the blog of Facebook show up on the other in the appropriate location.

Is there a way to do this with the Facebook API?

Comment: That would be nice. I'd also settle for being able to disable the comments on the facebook side and direct people to my blog to comment.

Comment: From what I can tell the plug-ins provided in the answers don't have the requested functionality. Is this the case?

Comment: probably @Casebash - but SU didn't exist when I asked :)

Comment: So, did you find a solution (I tried looking at the answers, but none of them seemed to work)?

Comment: Actually, I didn't read your last line, that you were looking for a way to do it with the API. Definitely belongs on SO then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of facebook-connect enabled WordPress plugins that might help you achieve this.
Here's a couple:

- [Sociable Facebook Connect](http://www.sociable.es/facebook-connect/)
- [WP-Facebook-Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-facebookconnect/)

Comment: I used the WP-Facebook-Connect plugin for a while, then decided I no longer wanted the integration :)

Comment: more than not wanting the integration was stopping facebook from importing my blog - which was effectively the same thing

Answer (score 1):

yoavf answer is good. A list including those plugins is maintained in Facebook's wiki:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Plugin_Directory

http://dentedreality.com.au/2008/12/implementing-facebook-connect-on-wordpress-in-reality has a novel approach that isn't on that list.

Comment: I read the dented reality post, but it didn't seem to solve the request problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to the source of the blog, figure out how the comment form is posted (POST or GET) then you can use mock ajax [documentation here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Mock_ajax). then inside the facebook app, you build a form similar to the one for the blog comment. make sure all the ids of the respective form elements are identical. then on your submit button you have a link like this.

```
<a  clickrewriteid="dummy" clickrewriteform="comment_form" 
clickrewriteurl="blog_form_action">Submit</a>
```

so *dummy* is the id of an element that will recieve any output.
*comment_form* is the id of the form that will be posted to the blog comment processor.
*blog_form_action* is the url in your blogs form action attribute.

if things work, the form *comment_form* will be posted to your blogs processor page so that the comment submitted from facebook will appear on the blog as well.

if the blog uses GET as its method, you just make sure that *blog_form_action* contains the query string

hope that helps!